# Spring ResourceBundleMessageSource is not loading a property file from a jar while ClassPathResource can

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss, resourcebundle

I am trying to load a message.properties file from a jar file, but it is not finding the file (and I have been trying for a few hours).

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>messages/messages</value>
            <value>classpath:org/common/messages/messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But it cannot find it:

```
[org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource] (http-/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080-5) ResourceBundle [classpath:org/common/messages/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name classpath:org/common/messages/messages, locale en_US
```

I have tried the following, and it does load the file, which I assume means the file is on the classpath

```
ClassPathResource cpr = new ClassPathResource("org/common/messages/messages.properties");
```

What is the difference?

I am running this on JBoss.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150869/resourcebundle-not-found-for-messagesource-when-placed-inside-a-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sample, from this POST - [Spring UTF-8 message resource from external jar proglem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956584/spring-utf-8-message-resource-from-external-jar-proglem)

```
<bean id="propertiesMessageSource"
class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="classpath:com/mypackage/i18n/messages" />
```

Comment: Fixed! `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` did the trick.